# How to disable some checkout steps in opencart?

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I need Billing Details, Delivery & Payment Method on the checkout page to be disabled because I don't need them. How can I do this or is there a module that can disable these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the store/admin under the "Extensions" menu and set everything in there the way you want it.
I know from experience that it will skip steps such as shipping if you don't have any defined, so that should be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already tried by disabling all shipping and payment options from Extensions>Shipping & Extensions>Payment but that only gives me the error "No Shipping options are available. Please contact us for assistance!" on the checkout page...

Comment: Oh, I forgot you have to enable the no shipping option for each product for that to work.

Comment: I enabled no-shipping then with some jquery I clicked on the continue button & hide the steps with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's nothing made already that could do this, and its really not something you're going to be able to do easily. A lot of the functionality uses address details. It's also part of the order insert details, and part of the order table, so it's going to be very hard to remove without breaking things

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to keep Address Details and just remove the other 3 things I mentioned. If I can't remove them is there a way to set the payment to free & delivery to paid on delivery by default and hide it someway on the checkout page?

Comment: It's something that could be done yes, but again its not easy. The checkout is very clumsy to modify